# Is iCloud supported with Ad Hoc Profiles?

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, testflight

my app works perfectly with my developer profile on my developer device but icloud doesn't work with ad hoc profiles with testflight.

Is it normal?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour.

Also, just something to note - since apple bought out testflight a few weeks ago, any app with the testflight SDK inside the project will be rejected/run into strange issues.

Your best bet for analytics is something like Flurry.

Comment: so it's normal that icloud doesn't work properly in ad hoc mode even without testflight?

Comment: Yes, is it normal behaviour. Unfortunate, but normal.

Comment: that's not normal. icloud works also for ad hoc provisioning profiles

Comment: @francesco289, Is iCloud working for you on ad hoc build? Thanks.